# mysql_num_rows опишите пожалуйста для чего он нужен?

Tags: php

Где используется для чего используется?

Comment: не актуально, удалено в php7+, ранее возвращал количество рядов результата запроса

Comment: А чем воcпользоватся вместо этого в php7?

Comment: @RovshanIbraqimov `PDO` - http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows() (сейчас это mysql**i**_num_rows (в ооп: $имя_переменной->*num_rows()*)) предназначен для просмотра кол-ва строк, которые выдал запрос в бд. Используется для скриптов **авторизации**, **регистрации** (например проверка на не занятость логина), **поиска** (например кол-во результатов) и т. д.